# Does the tungsten star topology allow all of them to be masters?

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, database-administration, tungsten-replicator, database

I want to configure a star topology.

There are 200+ vessels with 80 tables each and all of them are masters.

Also there is a central hub with all these 200 vessels as nodes.

Can anyone guide me in configuring a tungsten topology for this star topology?

Comment: I think you misunderstand, MongoDB doesn't have multimaster replication

Comment: Questions related to administration and configuration are better directed to [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/?newreg=3ed9e0f1c2454bf2bb8b61d7451f541d). Stack overflow is for programming related subjects.